# Using page dimentions in TikZ drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a simple question, but I do not know how to approach it.
I would like to use page dimensions in drawing and positioning of TikZ figures, so that figures are located identically when I change the size of my paper, for example from "lettersize" to "tabloid".
MWE below uses **coordinates** to draw a green rectangle:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[green, very thick] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I would like to achieve is this: one corner is located **1 in** from the left edge of the page and **1 in** below the top edge of the page, while the diagonal corner is located **1 in** from the right edge of the page and **5 in** above the bottom edge of the page.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[green, very thick] ([xshift=1in,yshift=-1in] current page.north west) rectangle ++ (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or with use of the `tikzpagenodes` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[green, very thick] (current page text area.north west) rectangle (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]